# Does EJB create new transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Does EJB(glassfish) create new transaction when i am executing a read only query using jpa(eclipselink).

Comment: do u mean that retrieving data do not need to be done within a transaction

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the `@TransactionAttribute` By defaults it is set to `Required` which means that if it's not running in transaction it will start one.

> The values of the TransactionAttribute annotation are defined by the enum TransactionAttributeType. If the TransactionAttribute annotation is not specified, and the bean uses container managed transaction demarcation, the semantics of the REQUIRED transaction attribute are assumed.

And the semantics of `Required`:

> If a client invokes the enterprise bean's method while the client is associated with a transaction context, the container invokes the enterprise bean's method in the client's transaction context.
>
> If the client invokes the enterprise bean's method while the client is not associated with a transaction context, the container automatically starts a new transaction before delegating a method call to the enterprise bean method.

More info:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html